# Как из кода управлять состоянием дочерних View в RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть `View`, который я генерирую в `RecyclerView`. В нажатом `View` есть дочерний элемент, к которому мне нужно получить доступ. Вопрос: как это лучше сделать? Создать класс со статическим `View` и задавать ему значение в `Holder'e` при нажатии на Item - я так понимаю, что это не самое идеальное решение, да и android studio ругается на возможную утечку памяти при использовании статических `View`...

Comment: Не очень ясно какую задачу вы решаете. У вас слушатель нажатий определён во ViewHolder или повешен на RecyclerView? Если последнее - то перенесите его в первый - так у вас будет доступ к элементам разметки. Если у вас имеется в виду изменение/сохранение состояния ячейки - то всё сложнее, в двух словах не объяснить

Comment: Да, во ViewHolder. Мне нужно обработать состояние ячейки при нажатии на Action в Notification и при запуске активности... Как мне изменить состояние видимости отдельного элемента во View из кода активности/фрагмента/сервиса?

Comment: По идее правильно будет так: в данных для списка хранить и текущее состояние оного. Когда надо состояние поменять - меняйте его в элементе списка данных и уведомляйте адаптер об изменениях - он перерисует.

Comment: Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. Не очень понятно, в чем именно у вас проблема. Возможно стоит добавить ваш код (только не полотно на 500 строк=))

Comment: Я уже решил эту проблему. Нужно было получить элемент макета, который служит шаблоном для заполнения списка и изменить его видимость в соответсвии с тем нажат он был или нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По хорошему вы не должны внутри RecyclerView.Adapter иметь какую-либо логику помимо логики биндинка элементов вашего RecyclerView.

Чтобы я вам рекомендовал? Создайте модель которая будет описывать состояние каждой вашей View. И работайте с ней в адаптере. Т.е. не просто список данных которые надо отобразить, а и другие параметры которые могут отражать состояние конкретных ваших View.

Далее в адаптере вам необходимо иметь метод update который будет обновлять ваш адаптер. Если вы не хотите каждый раз обновлять весь список, то посмотрите в сторону DiffUtils (он позволяет обновлять только те элементы которые изменились).

Хорошо бы ваш ClickListener вынести из адаптера во View в которой находится RecyclerView. И Обрабатывать логику где-то за пределами View (Presenter, ViewModel и т.д), а в адаптер передавать только обновленные данные.